# Удаление объекта из массива в NodeJS или неправленый скрипт?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Суть проблемы такова, что скрипт работает немного не правильно... Не могу самостоятельно разобраться.

Есть массив объектов :

```
var routes = [ 
    { path: '/login', methods: [ 'GET' ] },
    { path: '/login', methods: [ 'POST' ] },
    { path: '/admin', methods: [ 'GET' ] },
    { path: '/admin', methods: [ 'POST' ] },
    { path: '/admin', methods: [ 'PUT' ] },
    { path: '/admin/mylogin', methods: [ 'GET' ] },
    { path: '/admin/mylogin', methods: [ 'POST' ] },
    { path: '/admin/mylogin/:user', methods: [ 'GET' ] },
    { path: '/admin/mylogin/:user', methods: [ 'POST' ] },
    { path: '/client', methods: [ 'GET' ] },
    { path: '/client', methods: [ 'POST' ] },
    { path: '/client/123', methods: [ 'GET' ] },
    { path: '/client/123', methods: [ 'POST' ] },
    { path: '/client/123', methods: [ 'DELETE' ] },
    { path: '/client/123', methods: [ 'PUT' ] },
    { path: '/', methods: [ 'GET' ] }
];
```

Нужно выбрать все совпадения `path` и запушить из совпавших в искомый `methods` и удалить совпавший.

Скрипт:

```
routes.forEach((element, i) => {
    j = 0;
    while(j < routes.length) {
        if (routes[j].path === element.path && routes[j].methods !== element.methods) {
            element.methods.push(routes[j].methods[0]);
            routes.splice(j,1)
        }
        j++
    }
});
```

В итоге у меня там где 4 и более совпавших элемента примерно такое:

```
  { path: '/client/123', methods: [ 'POST', 'GET', 'DELETE' ] },
  { path: '/client/123', methods: [ 'PUT' ] }
```

А должно быть :

```
{ path: '/client/123', methods: [ 'POST', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT' ] }
```

Пробовал и `delete routes[j]`, но там удаление срабатывает вообще раньше чем выполняется условие и NodeJS ругается, что `routes[j].path` не определено.

Answer (score 3):

В качестве альтернативного варианта, можно использовать [метод `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) для группировки по полю `path`

```
var routeByPaths = routes.reduce((acc,cur)=>{
    if(!acc[cur.path]){
        acc[cur.path] = cur;
    }else{
        acc[cur.path].push(...cur.methods)
    }
    return acc;
},{});
```

Получится объект, в котором ключами будут пути, а значениями объекты начального массива с измененным полем `methods`

Для получения массива значений можно воспользоваться методом [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```
routes = Object.values(routeByPaths);
```

---

Если в повторяемых путях в массиве `methods` могут повторяться методы, например:

```
{ path: '/client', methods: [ 'GET' ] },
{ path: '/client', methods: [ 'POST' ] },
{ path: '/client', methods: [ 'GET' ] },
{ path: '/client', methods: [ 'POST' ] },
```

То в промежуточных расчетах лучше использовать [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) вместо массива, так как он не допускает повторения элементов.

Например:

```
var routeByPaths = routes.reduce((acc,cur)=>{
    if(!acc[cur.path]){
        acc[cur.path] = { path:[cur.path], methods: new Set() };
    }
    cur.methods.reduce((set,method)=>{
        set.add(method);
        return set;
    }, acc[cur.path].methods)
    return acc;
},{});
```

И далее, при получении, если нужен именно массив. то можно преобразовать Set в массив, например так:

```
routes = Object.values(routeByPaths).map(el=>({path:el.path, methods:[...el.methods]}));
```

Comment: спасибо большое за решения и пояснения, очень интересно)))

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у меня получилось, и оно даже работает))))

```
routes.forEach((element, i, arr) => {
    j = arr.length-1;
    while(j >=0) {
        if (j !== i && element.path === arr[j].path) {
            element.methods.push(arr[j].methods[0])
            arr.splice(j, 1)
        }
        j--
    }
});
```

А вот такое решение мне предложили на тостере:

```
    const groupedRoutes = Object.values(routes.reduce((map, { path, methods }) => {
    map[path] =  map[path] ?
     { path, methods: [ ...map[path].methods, ...methods ] } :
     { path, methods };

    return map;
  },{}));
```

Answer (score -1):

У вас ошибка из-за работы с  `j`. Вы делаете `routes.splice(j,1)`, а потом `j++`. В итоге пропускаете один элемент. После `routes.splice(j,1)` нужно делать `j--`.

И кстати, `routes[j].methods !== element.methods` не работает, т.к. нельзя массивы таким образом сравнивать.

К тому же, плохая практика обращаться к `routes` из `forEach`.

Что-то типо такого должно быть:

```
routes.forEach((element, index, object) => {
    var j = 0;
    while (j < object.length) {
        // нет смысла с самим собой работать
        if(object[j] !== element){
            if (object[j].path === element.path) {
                for(var mIndex = 0; mIndex < object[j].methods.length; ++mIndex){
                    if(element.methods.indexOf(object[j].methods[mIndex]) === -1){
                        element.methods.push(object[j].methods[mIndex]);
                    }
                }
                object.splice(j, 1);
                j--;
            }
        }

        j++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75739/discussion-on-answer-by-suvitruf------nodejs--).